# showing that a function is O(something) (big O notation)

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have a problem understanding how to solve the big-O-notation equations, such as this one:

```
f(n) = 10n + 5 and g(n) = n
Show that f(n) is O(g(n))
```

Taken from here: http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~booth/311-01/notes/bigOex.html

It says there that `To show f(n) is O(g(n)) we must show constants c and k such that f(n) <= cg(n) for all n >=k`

I get that: Starting from k, f(n) will not grow faster than g(n) times an arbitrary constant.

What I don't get is this:

```
We are allowed to choose c and k to be integers we want as long as they 
are positive.  They can be as big as we want, but they can't be functions
of n.
```

So in order to solve those equations, I can **always** choose c and k as long as they meet those requirements? But if I can choose k, then why do they calculate k on that website?

```
Try c = 15.  Then we need to show: 10n + 5 <= 15n.
             Solving for n we get: 5 <= 5n  or 1 <= n.
So f(n) = 10+5 <= 15g(n) for all n >= 1.  (c = 15, k = 1)
```

Comment: Yes. You could also show that `lim_{n->infinity}(f(n) / g(n)) < infinity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, they want to show that, beyond a given value of n, c * g(n) is always >= f(n). So if you set k to that value, the inequality holds. It is not necessary to show *precisely* beyond which point it holds (i.e. the minimum valid value for k given some arbitrary c) -- it just happens to become obvious when solving the inequality.

As long as you can prove there exists *some* c, k for which that holds, you can say f(n) is O(g(n)).